# Conda environment activation fails in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

When I launch a Python terminal or use Shift+Enter to run code from my Python Files through VS Code on Windows, I get a message:

> This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment
>   has not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this
>   environment please see https://conda.io/activation.

I get a Python prompt. The code runs as expected.  If I exit() that prompt and run "conda activate myenv", the environment activates and I can then run python using the desired environment. However, I can't seem to figure out why it's not activating by default.

I have the MS Python module loaded. Conda is up to date and in my system path. I've installed Conda into cmd and powershell. And the expect "activate" command works if I quit python and type it in. Any ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have this setting in your `settings.json` file,

```
"python.pythonPath": "<anacondapath>\\envs\\<yourenv>\\python.exe",
```

This should automatically load the conda environment for you.

Comment: No luck. Still get the same message about the environment not being activated.

Comment: Delete current terminal and press `Ctrl +  backquote`. Does this open up a new terminal with and run the command `conda activate <yourenv>` ?

Comment: Ctrl+` just opens a windows terminal.  I have no issues running "conda activate env"  For some reason I get that error when launching a Python console or using Shift+Enter to run highlighted code.